# Pass value from nested react component childs to the form onSubmit handle function

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, reactjs

I'm new with Reactjs and I'm trying to use this.refs.myComponent to get the value of an imput field, but this input field is nested in another react component. Let me share an example of what I mean:

Imagine that i have this:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    onFormSubmit(e) {
        console.log(this.refs.childName);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <ChildComponent refName='childName'/>
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input type='text' ref={this.props.refValue} name={this.props.refValue} id={this.props.refValue}/>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call this.refs.childName I can't take the value as part of the form submit event without doing something like evt.target.childName.value?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, refs are not the preferred way to handle passing UI data (state in React) down to child components. It's better to avoid using refs when possible.

[This](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) is a great explanation of the relationship between props, and components.

And [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) explains state and some of the core beliefs about state within the React framework.

So here is an example to accomplish what you are trying to do, in a "React friendly" way. Your ChildComponent can be [stateless](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d), so it only has one responsibility, to render the props passed down to it, whose props handled as state in ParentComponent.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
   return (
     <input 
        type='text' 
        value={props.textValue} 
        onChange={props.onTextChange}
     />
   )
}

class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
      this.onTextChange = this.onTextChange.bind(this)

      this.state = {
        textValue: ''
      }
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(`You typed: ${this.state.textValue}`)
    }

    onTextChange(e) {
      this.setState({textValue: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <ChildComponent 
                  textValue={this.state.textValue}
                  onTextChange={this.onTextChange}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

// assumes you have an element with an id of 'root'
// in the root html file every React app has
ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I would strongly recommend using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to get a quick and easy React app running without doing anything.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen... that's exactly what I was looking for.